# Whirl effect with HLSL, starting from Microsoft SpriteEffects sample

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, hlsl

[The sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_effects)

If you watch the code, I'm interested in `refraction.fx`, and in `void DrawRefractGlacier(GameTime gameTime)` function. Here you can notice that the function uses a texture to render water distortion on an image (`waterfall.jpg` as "distorter image", and `glacier.jpg` as distorted image).

If you read inside `refraction.fx`, at the beginning it says:

```
// Effect uses a scrolling displacement texture to offset the position of the main
// texture. Depending on the contents of the displacement texture, this can give a
// wide range of refraction, rippling, warping, and swirling type effects.
```

It seems that would be easy to achieve another effect by changing the image. I tried that with an image like this:

[image: My image]

I want to achieve the effect of distorting everything around as a rotating whirl, or a spiral. How can I do that?

Some simple sequential screen of how it looks with my texture:

[image: Screen1]
[image: Screen2]
[image]

Refraction shader:

```
// Effect uses a scrolling displacement texture to offset the position of the main
// texture. Depending on the contents of the displacement texture, this can give a
// wide range of refraction, rippling, warping, and swirling type effects.

float2 DisplacementScroll;
float2 angle;

sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);
sampler DisplacementSampler : register(s1);

float2x2 RotationMatrix(float rotation)   
{   
    float c = cos(rotation);   
    float s = sin(rotation);   

    return float2x2(c, -s, s ,c);   
}  

float4 main(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
   float2 rotated_texcoord = texCoord;   
        rotated_texcoord -= float2(0.25, 0.25);   
        rotated_texcoord = mul(rotated_texcoord, RotationMatrix(angle));   
        rotated_texcoord += float2(0.25, 0.25);   

    float2 DispScroll = DisplacementScroll;

    // Look up the displacement amount.
    float2 displacement = tex2D(DisplacementSampler, DispScroll+ texCoord / 3);

    // Offset the main texture coordinates.
    texCoord += displacement * 0.2 - 0.15;

    // Look up into the main texture.
    return tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord) * color;
}


technique Refraction
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 main();
    }
}
```

Its draw call:

```
void DrawRefractGlacier(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Set an effect parameter to make the
    // displacement texture scroll in a giant circle.
    refractionEffect.Parameters["DisplacementScroll"].SetValue(
                                                MoveInCircle(gameTime, 0.2f));

    // Set the displacement texture.
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = waterfallTexture;

    // Begin the sprite batch.
    spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, refractionEffect);

    // Because the effect will displace the texture coordinates before
    // sampling the main texture, the coordinates could sometimes go right
    // off the edges of the texture, which looks ugly. To prevent this, we
    // adjust our sprite source region to leave a little border around the
    // edge of the texture. The displacement effect will then just move the
    // texture coordinates into this border region, without ever hitting
    // the edge of the texture.

    Rectangle croppedGlacier = new Rectangle(32, 32,
                                             glacierTexture.Width - 64,
                                             glacierTexture.Height - 64);

    spriteBatch.Draw(glacierTexture,
                     GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds,
                     croppedGlacier,
                     Color.White);

    // End the sprite batch.
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Comment: Just a first thought: Atm the refraction is scrolled over the screen, in you case you should transform the displacement-values with an rotation-matrix to get a spinning distoration. Could you show the result you get distorting with your image? Maybe you have to generate a spiral, instead of drawing it by hand.

Comment: Are these screens enough, or should I try to make a video?

Comment: They're sufficient I think. It looks like your image is stretched over the whole screen and not really in the center. Do you turned off the scrolling effect in the shader?

Comment: I didn't touched anything but loading my image... Yes, it seems that it is streached over the Whole screen!